# Gradle Plugin: Error on JavaExec run

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I'm trying to create a gradle java plugin to do various tasks for setting up a mod workspace for a java game, to learn techniques.

I have a task to try and run Procyon on the jars as follows, where `jar` is an nio File and `out` is an nio Path:

```
ExecResult res = getProject().javaexec(act -> {
        act.executable(DecompileConstants.PROCYON_JAR);
        act.setMain("-jar");
        act.args("-jar", jar.getAbsolutePath(), "-o", out.toAbsolutePath());
        act.workingDir(DecompileConstants.WORKING_DIR.toFile());

        act.setStandardOutput(System.out);
        getLogger().lifecycle(": Running " + act.getExecutable());
    });
```

I am, however, receiving what seems to be a common error from gradle upon running the decompile task:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

What would be the best way to go about debugging this issue to get this task working? It needs to be done in JAVA as there are already existing tasks in the codebase. I'm working with Gradle 3.1 (the latest at time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the jar was invalid and was missing its main class. This error was far from helpful, but that's what did it.

Always double check your jars in a command line, I suppose.